# Horizontal lines between vertices do not render

Tags: java, libgdx, 3d-meshes

Good day,

I am using LibGDX to try to render a mesh for a hexagon board. I can render the triangles, which is great, but I am having an issue rendering all of the line segments for the mesh and I can't figure out why.

---

### Pictures

Here is an image of what it renders with the primitive type set to GL_TRIANGLES. The colours are just to help me troubleshoot/identify which triangles are where.
[image: triangles]
.

Here is an image of what it renders with the primitive type set to GL_LINES. Whether there is 1 triangle being rendered or 1 million, the horizontal lines do not get rendered.
[image: lines]
.

---

### Code

How I create the mesh:

```
mesh = new Mesh(true, MAX_VERTS, 0, 
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, POSITION_COMPONENTS, "a_position"),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorUnpacked, COLOR_COMPONENTS, "a_color"));

mesh.setVertices(verts);

renderable = new Renderable();
renderable.mesh = mesh;
renderable.primitiveType = GL20.GL_TRIANGLES;
renderable.meshPartSize = mesh.getNumVertices();
renderable.meshPartOffset = 0;
```

When I switch the renderable.primitiveType to GL20.GL_LINES I get the 2nd picture from above.

I've tried to set the renderable.meshPartSize a couple of different ways:

```
renderable.primitiveType = GL20.GL_LINES;

renderable.meshPartSize = mesh.getNumVertices(); // Doesn't work
renderable.meshPartSize = MAX_VERTS * 2;         // Doesn't work
```

Here is how I make a triangle:

```
void drawTriangle(float x, float y, float z, float width, float height, Color color) {  
    // Counter-clockwise winding

    // Vertex 1: Top Left
    verts[idx++] = x;
    verts[idx++] = y;
    verts[idx++] = z;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    // Vertex 2: Bottom Left
    verts[idx++] = x;
    verts[idx++] = y;
    verts[idx++] = z + height;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    // Vertex 3: Top Right      
    verts[idx++] = x + width;
    verts[idx++] = y;
    verts[idx++] = z;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that GL_LINES takes two vertices at a time, so for every two triangles (a, b, c) and (d, e, f), it'll render three lines (a, b), (c, d) and (e, f)?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it wouldn't render line (c, a) or (f, d). Is there an alternative to use instead so that I can get all 5 lines to appear rather than 3?

Comment: Well if you want to draw 3 lines per triangle, then you need to send 6 vertices (3 will be duplicates of the other 3). Alternatively, draw the triangles but with `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` set, for wireframe rendering.

Comment: If you don't mind please post an answer cause I would like to see how you made this work.

Answer (score 1):

Using GL_LINE_STRIP worked for me, you could give that a try if you have not solved this yet.